# Write many files in a for loop

Tags: r

I have sample data like this

```
df <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:7], each = 24), salary = runif(24*7, 100, 200))
```

I wanted to separate each name with their salaries

```
lst <- tapply(df$salary, df$name, matrix, nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Now I want to write all these 7 matrices to 7 different text files, It is working only for a single matrix at a time. I tried to put in a for loop but is not working

```
for (i in 1:7)
{
write.table(lst[i], ".txt", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
}
```

Can any one suggest for the modifications in the for loop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given your `lst`, the following will write this out to a series of TXT files with names equal to the name of `lst`, plus `.txt`:

```
lapply(names(lst),
       function(x, lst) write.table(lst[[x]], paste(x, ".txt", sep = ""),
                                    col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep="\t", 
                                    quote=FALSE),
       lst)
```

To modify your `for()` loop, try:

```
for(i in seq_along(lst)) {
    write.table(lst[[i]], paste(names(lst)[i], ".txt", sep = ""), 
                col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
}
```

The problem was trying to or assuming R would paste together the filenames for you.

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
for (ii in names(lst)){
  filename <- paste(ii, ".txt", sep="")
  write.table(lst[[ii]], filename, col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,sep="\t",quote=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So we have to add another statement in the for loop for saving the filenames...great

Comment: no, you can directly pass ``write.table(lst[[ii]], paste(ii, ".txt", sep=""), col.names=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,sep="\t",quote=FALSE)`` but I thought it would be clearer in two lines.