# How can I write to many different files using a for loop in R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [writing many files in a for loop using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033699/writing-many-files-in-a-for-loop-using-r)

I am trying to figure our how I can write data to many different files using a for loop:

for example:

```
for (i in 1:4)
{

x = i
write(x, file = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\R_stuff\\testi.txt", append = FALSE, sep = ",")

}
```

I want to create 4 text files: test1 that contains 1; test2 that contains 2; test3 that contains 3; test 4 that contains 4.

However, I don't know the syntax that will allow the loop the change the name of the text file on each iteration. Obviously my "testi.txt" doesn't work :).

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save to multiple files you need to construct a custom filename inside the loop. An option is paste:

```
paste("basename", i, ".bla", sep = "")
```

alternatively:

```
sprintf("basename%s.bla", i)
```

Comment: or maybe better (if you have more than 9 files): `sprintf("file%03d.bla", i)`; that will make like file001, file002, etc.