# Write to files in R using a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, write.table

I have several variables as follow:

```
cats <- "some long text with info"
dogs <- "some long text with info"
fish <- "some long text with info"
....
```

and I manually write the content of these variables into a text file:

```
write.table(cats, "info/cats.txt", sep="\t")
write.table(dogs, "info/dogs.txt", sep="\t")
....
```

I read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033699/writing-many-files-in-a-for-loop-using-r) and tried to write a loop to automatically write the files.

So I created a list:

```
lst <<- list(cats, dogs,fish, ....)
```

and then iterated through the list:

```
for(i in seq_along(lst)) {
    write.table(lst[[i]], paste(names(lst)[i], ".txt", sep = ""), 
               col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE,  sep = "\t")
}
```

but the output of the above iteration is **one text file** called `.txt` and it contains the content of the **last variable** in the list.

any idea why the above loop doesn't work as expected?

Comment: `is.null(names(lst)); #[1] TRUE`

Comment: @nrussell that returns `TRUE`

Comment: Yes -- you did not name your list. Equivalently, `paste0(NULL, ".txt")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the following:

```
> cats <- "some long text with info"
> dogs <- "some long text with info"
> fish <- "some long text with info"
> lst <- list(cats, dogs,fish)  # not <<-
> names(lst)
NULL
```

When you created your list, you didn't give it any names, so your loop doesn't have anything to work with. A fix:

```
> names(lst) <- c("cats", "dogs", "fish")
```

Comment: thanks, I thought the name is automatically selected from the list

Comment: Named arguments will become list names, e.g., `list = list(cats = cats, name_of_dog_item = dogs, fish_here = fish)` will have names `"cats"`, `"name_of_dog_item"`, etc.

Comment: Alternatively, `mget` will name your list automatically: `mget(c("cats", "dogs", "fish"))`.

Comment: @HongOoi is it possible to create a loop for the first part too?