# subsetting tables in for loop and saving them as csv

Tags: r

I am very new to R and am trying to use it for generating a very large number of subsets (>4000), which my current script in JSL cannot handle. i would greatly appreciate if anyone could give me pointers on going about subsetting a table like the one below and saving them as `.csv` using column name and row info.

```
set.seed(24)
DT = data.frame(Group=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),Output1 = rnorm(9),Output2=rnorm(9),Output3=rnorm(9),Step=c("0","0","1","1","1","1","2","2","2"))
DT
```

I would like to subset this by `Group,Output[i]`, Step and save as `.csv` files with a particular naming convention "`column_Step_Group.csv`". Examples shown below

```
Output1_0_A.csv

-0.5458808
0.5365853


Output2_0_A.csv
0.002311942
-1.316908124  

Output1_2_B.csv
0.4445853
-0.4664951
-0.8483700
```

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible example of your data? It would help a lot to have a data frame that can be copied and pasted into R so that it is unambiguous what your data structure is. The thing you pasted there is pretty confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by "subset this by ... Output[i]"? Is "Output[i] part of the grouping logic? For which "i"? Or do you just want to put all values if the i-th output column into the result file (as indicated in the example output)?

Comment: @Slow Ioris - i have added the data frame. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @ R Yoda, yes to the latter - would like the values of the i-th output column into the result file for the given Group and Step. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [writing many files in a for loop using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033699/writing-many-files-in-a-for-loop-using-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of `data.frame`s.  Loop through the names of the 'lst' (`lapply(names(lst),...`) and use `fwrite` from `data.table` (for faster writing).

```
lst <- split(DT[-c(1,5)], list(DT$Group, DT$Step), drop=TRUE)
library(data.table)
invisible(lapply(names(lst), function(x) {
      l1 <- split.default(lst[[x]], names(lst[[x]]))
      lapply(names(l1), function(y)  fwrite(l1[[y]],
             paste0(y, "_", x, ".csv")))}))
```

The output of  "Output1_A.0.csv"

```
 Output1
-0.545880758
0.536585304
```

Comment: Hello Akrun - thanks for providing this code. I tried running it as is and am getting the following error   "Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
"      Can you please help me understand what could be going wrong for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user6354897  I am not getting any error based on the example you showed

Comment: Was getting the error because fwrite doesnt seem to work. Here is a modification of the above code and it works great. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: DT = data.frame(Group=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),Output1 = rnorm(9),Output2=rnorm(9),Output3=rnorm(9),Step=c("0","0","1","1","1","1","2","2","2"))
lst <- split(DT[-c(1,5)], list(DT$Group, DT$Step), drop=TRUE)
library(data.table)
invisible(lapply(names(lst), function(x) {
  l1 <- split.default(lst[[x]], names(lst[[x]]))
  lapply(names(l1), function(y)  write.table(l1[[y]],
                                        paste0(y, "_", x, ".csv"), row.names=FALSE))}))

Comment: @user6354897  I guess I am using the devel version of data.table which has this function.  It would be fast with fwrite.

Answer (score 1):

Or in loop

```
DT = data.frame(Group=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),Output1 = rnorm(9),Output2=rnorm(9),Output3=rnorm(9),Step=c("0","0","1","1","1","1","2","2","2"))

for(i in levels(DT$Group)) {
  da <- subset(DT, Group == i)
  write.csv(da, paste("Group_", i, ".csv", sep = ""),  row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Please check the expected output in the OP's post

Comment: The above loop does split out the files, but i wanted to add two more constraints - selection of Step and Output[i].  I tried writing nested loops by tinkering with the code above, but am not able to subset desired columns.for (k in 1:length(column))

{

for(i in levels(DT$Group)) 
{

for(j in levels(DT$Step))
{
  da <- subset(DT, Group == i & Step == j & colnames(DT) == column[k])
  write.csv(da, paste("Group_", i, j, column[k], ".csv", sep = ""),  row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
}
}
}         is there anyway select few columns can be subsetted in the final output? thanks!!

Comment: have you tested @akrun solution?