# Import and process Multiple My SQL tables separately in R

Tags: mysql, r

I have a number of summary tables located in a mysql database. The database names are labelled as follows. I have created a list of these filenames-
databasenameslist

```
AAA_1
AAA_2
AAA_3
AAA_4
AAA_5
AAA_6
AAA_7
```

The databases each contain a summary table. The names of these are as follows and are in the  form of a list- querylist

```
AAA_1_Summary
AAA_2_Summary
AAA_3_Summary
AAA_4_Summary
AAA_5_Summary
AAA_6_Summary
AAA_7_Summary
```

Each table has a set of variables. I am running a random forest on the variables.

table AAA_1

```
   Variable1    Variable2   Variable3   Outcome
     A           1           123         100
     B           2           145         150
     C           3           167         130
     D           4           111         111
     A           5           133         123
     B           6          131.6        111
```

I want to import each table via an RMySQL query and a for loop. I Want to run a random forest on each table separately and the output should be written to a separate series of files.

I have tried the following code

```
  require(RMySQL)# Import library
  require(DBI)# import library
  require(sqldf)# import library
  require(dbConnect)
  username = 'username'
  userpass = 'userpass'
  hostname = '111.11.11.1111'

  for (i in databasenameslist){
                      cdb<-i}
 for(i in querylist){
                      Query<- i}

  cdbconn = dbConnect(MySQL(), user=username, password=userpass, 
  dbname=cdb[i], 
  host=hostname)
```

The above step is to connect each db separately. Now each file has to be read. For this, I am using the following code.
      database<-dbGetQuery(cdbconn, paste(querylist[i]))

The code above does not work.

Note: The final solution will be similar to this code: [Write many files in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033699/write-many-files-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: One step at a time: First figure out how to get all your data from MySQL into R.  By the way, having so many different databases and tables has a smell to me.

Comment: i am able to read the data from a single table.And yes if by smell you mean complicated, It is. Comparitively new to rmysql

Comment: I might write a query which aggregates all the data together, e.g. via a `UNION`, and then bring that into a single data frame.

Comment: That yes. But the output for each input table needs to be separate. Thats a snag

Comment: *The code above does not work.* ... is not helpful at all. What is the error? Undesired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `Map` to iterate through both lists element-wise since you do not need to nest the looping. Also, add `SELECT * FROM` to your querylist names to send appropariate SQL calls.

```
# IF QUERYLIST IS A CHARACTER VECTOR
querylist <- paste0("SELECT * FROM ", querylist)

# IF QUERYLIST IS A LIST
querylist <- lapply(querylist, function(q) paste0("SELECT * FROM ", q))

proc_data <- function(db, qry) {      
   conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user=username, password=userpass, dbname=db, host=hostname)
   df <- dbGetQuery(conn, qry)    
   dbDisconnect(conn)

   # ... DO OTHER WORK ON DF: random forest, csv output    

   return(df)    # OR WHATEVER OTHER OBJ IN PROCESSING
}

df_List <- Map(proc_data, databasenameslist, querylist)
```

Comment: This Works Well. Tank You. I am getting an error in RMySQL import.

Comment: @ parfait, the first two parts are done. Thank you. the map command is generating an error. Wil check the same.

Comment: The error is different. It pertains to one of the tables being read. It has zero rows. Seems my colleague had not created the same.

Answer (score 1):

I did not put the code for the random forest in here. I'm not familiar enough to give you an answer on that but maybe you can edit this loop to give you what you want. But here is the code to loop through your databases and summary tables and put the results of each query into a new R Data Frame. Move the code for cdbconn up with the rest of your password and username variables.

```
`for (i in 1:length(databasenamelist)){
     query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s.%s',databasenamelist[i],querylist[i])
     assign(paste0('table',databasenamelist[i]), dbGetQuery(cdbconn, query))
}`
```